# show popup message on button click without saving data to database

Tags: android, popup, alert, toast

I am new to android and getting problems in showing popup message.

**My problem is:**

The popup message is coming fine when some required field is missed to fill on the click of a save button but the field values are still getting saved into the database.

They should only be saved if all the required fields are filled by the user.

My code logic is inside the save button onClick listener method in the fragment.

```
Button save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save);

save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
  if(isAlert)
  {
    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter the required fields to proceed!",    
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
  }

  createOrModifyTables(); //Database table save logic

  //More then 1000 lines of code.....

}
```

I want to skip more then 1000 lines of code and the `createOrModifyTables()` method after I return in the if condition. I can't just put `createOrModifyTables()` inside the if condition.

Comment: you not put an else on the if and get rid of the return, that way it shouldnt do the else when it passes the if statement

Comment: Is it the only way to skip the remaining  part that I need to put more then 1000 lines of code in the else part  ?

Comment: on the OnCLick function print vale of 'isAlert', commit the 'createOrModifyTables()' code and see if data are saved somewhere else in you code